# Objective C - Help with UIButton showing variable Titles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

First off I am a rookie so any help is appreciated.  I have written the following code to change the title of the button every time it is initiated.  When I test the code, I can see the new button label for a fraction of a second and then the button is blank again (as it had started off).  I only see the first three touches, so I am thinking that there is also something wrong with my counting method.  The code is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
static int counter = 0;

if (counter == 0) {
    [[sender titleLabel] setText:@"not answered"];
}else if (counter == 1) {
    [[sender titleLabel] setText:@"Pressed Once"];
}else if (counter == 2) {
    [[sender titleLabel] setText:@"Pressed Twice"];
}
counter += 1;

if (counter >2) {
    counter = 0;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use:

```
[(UIButton *)sender setTitle:@"XXX" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Setting the label directly isn't going to work because it's manipulated internally by the button logic.

Comment: +1 You'll also want to set its `UIControlStateHighlighted` to your new text or the button text will change to its old state when the user taps down on it.

Comment: Thanks!  Works great after I made your suggested changes and changed the logic of the counters.

Comment: Incidentally, if you know only buttons will send events to pressButton, you can make the first argument a (UIButton *) directly.  It doesn't have to be a generic id.